# Launching a second application from a first one, then close the first one

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-2.0, launching-application

Is it a good practice in C#.Net to launch application B from application A, then close application A? Could there eventually be thread problems / bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any guidance on such a thing.

If you start a *new* process (Application B) from your Application A, they are considered completely separate.

If you then terminate the Application A process, it would not interfere with Application B.

The only issue I can see is if Application B is trying to access files that are still open by Application A (while it shuts down).

Comment: Ok. So it is possible to base a software update on this very basic pattern. Thanks!

Comment: @LéonPelletier - Well, yes. Most software updates are run through a specialized update application that updates the other components of the system (and get into trouble when they need to update themselves...)

Comment: So the main app should also be aware about the good updater version. :) Thank.